# Spring Integration ftp inboud channel processing files in specific order

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm using Spring Integration to poll files from remote FTP server and process them.

Is there a way to configure FtpInboundFileSynchronizer (or other component) to fetch and process remote files in specific order. Say i have file1 and file2 in remote directory, is it possible to fetch and process file1 before file2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) 3 techniques to achieve this:

1. Add a custom `FileListFilter<FTPFile>` (that sorts the `FTPFile` objects into the order you desire) to the synchronizer.
2. Use two FTP outbound gateways, one the list (ls) the files, and one to get each file as needed.
3. Use the `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` from within your own code to list and fetch files.

**EDIT**

Actually, for #1, you would also need a custom `FileListFilter<File>` in the local filter to sort the `File` objects. Since the local files are emitted as message payloads after the synchronization is complete.

**EDIT2 Remote file template example**

This just copies the first file in the list, but it should give you what you need...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49462148Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49462148Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(FtpRemoteFileTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            FTPFile[] files = template.list("*.txt");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(files));
            template.get(files[0].getName(), is -> {
                File file = new File("/tmp/" + files[0].getName());
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                FileCopyUtils.copy(is, os);
                System.out.println("Copied: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            });
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("...");
        sf.setUsername("...");
        sf.setPassword("...");
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpRemoteFileTemplate template(DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf) {
        FtpRemoteFileTemplate template = new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(sf);
        template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("foo"));
        return template;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. Any samples to point me to using FtpRemoteFileTemplate?

Comment: I added a simple example to my answer.