# Download file by specific file name using FtpOutboundGateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-rest

I'm implementing a service using Spring boot to download a single pattern-based file from an ftp server. The file name in the pattern changes based on the client's request parameters. And the file shouldn't be saved locally.

I'm new to this and I couldn't find a good explanation on how to achieve this using FtpOutboundGateway and Java config. Please help.

Here's some sample to show where I was taking this:

FtpOutboundGateway bean:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
public FtpOutboundGateway ftpFileGateway() {
    FtpOutboundGateway ftpOutboundGateway =
                      new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "get", "'Ready_Downloads/'");
    ftpOutboundGateway.setOptions("-P -stream");
    ftpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannelName("downloadChannel");
    return ftpOutboundGateway;
}
```

Use of autowired OutboundGateway ftpFileGateway bean in service endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] downloadFile(@RequestPart Map<String, String> fileDetails) throws Exception
{
    String filename = fileDetails.get("filename");

        FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter filter = new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter( "*"+filename+"*");
        ftpFileGateway.setFilter(filter);

        //then what?...
}
```

I'm assuming I might need to use the input and output message channels, just not sure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the gateway for each request; it's not thread-safe.

You don't need a filter at all; simply send the `fileName` as the payload of the message sent to the `get` gateway and set the gateway expression to...

```
new FtpOutboundGateway(ftpSessionFactory(), "get", 
    "'Ready_Downloads/' + payload"
```

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49516152Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49516152Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner (Gate gate) {
        return args -> {
            InputStream is = gate.get("bar.txt");
            File file = new File("/tmp/bar.txt");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            FileCopyUtils.copy(is, os);
            System.out.println("Copied: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        };
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpGet")
    @Bean
    public FtpOutboundGateway getGW() {
        FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(sf(), "get", "'foo/' + payload");
        gateway.setOption(Option.STREAM);
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("...");
        sf.setUsername("...");
        sf.setPassword("...");
        return sf;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "ftpGet")
    public interface Gate {

        InputStream get(String fileName);

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use a pattern to retrieve a file? Also how would I get the data stream from `FtpOutboundGateway`? Thanks @gary-russell

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "pattern to get a file". You can use MGET to get multiple files matching a pattern. When using [get with the `-stream` option](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway), the reply message has the input stream in its payload. By default, the gateway copies the file to disk and send the `File` object in the reply payload.

Comment: You could also use an `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` within your controller instead of the gateway [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49462148/spring-integration-ftp-inboud-channel-processing-files-in-specific-order/49465640#49465640).

Comment: For the pattern, I meant setting the `filename-pattern` mentioned in the docs. If possible any samples on how to accomplish this using the gateway, and retrieve the inpustream, would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more explicit. What documentation are you talking about? I can see `filename-pattern` talked about in the MGET command. Patterns/filters only apply when multiple files are involved - LS and MGET commands. I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes if you would please add to the example and use MGET with the `filename-pattern`. Also with the concern about thread-safety, how would I use the messaging gateway proxy for each new download request on my service endpoint?

Comment: You can't get a stream with MGET you can only copy the matching files to a local file system. You can't change the filter dynamically. You could implement a filter that uses a `ThreadLocal` however.